# Can't Install React Typical

Tags: reactjs

I tried to install react typical, but then It seems won't works.

I am using this command `npm i react-typical` then I got error like below:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: random@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!   react-typical@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-06T13_20_53_259Z-debug-0.log
```

I have no idea what went wrong here, I tried to find some helps on google but could not find it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

See details on legacy peer dependancies [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps).

You can also try:

```
npm install react-typical --force
```

If that doesn't work, see this [website](https://howtojs.io/how-to-resolve-eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error/#:%7E:text=When%20you%20try%20to%20install%20an%20Angular%20or,peerDependency%20conflict%2C%20it%20will%20through%20the%20error%20message.) for other solutions such as downgrading NPM.

Comment: i tried it, and then using the same command again above it gives the same error

Comment: @aldo I edited my solution above, try them out